# copy one arraylist to another arraylist in kotlin

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

I am trying to copy one `ArrayList` to another `ArrayList` in Kotlin

1st `ArrayList`:

```
private var leadList1: ArrayList<Lead> = ArrayList()
```

2nd `ArrayList`:

```
val leadList2: ArrayList<Lead?>?
```

I tried to use `addAll()`. `leadList1.addAll(leadList2)`

But its not working.

Error showing:

```
Required: Collection<Lead>
Found: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Lead?>?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't safe to do, because your first list can only contain objects of type `Lead`, while your second one has `Lead?` as its type parameter, meaning that it might contain `null` values. You can't add those to the first list.

The solution for this problem will depend on your context, but you can either let the first list contain nullable elements too:

```
private var leadList1: ArrayList<Lead?> = ArrayList()
```

Or you can add only the non-null elements of the second list to the first one:

```
leadList1.addAll(leadList2.filterNotNull())
```

And in either case, you'll have to perform a null check on `leadList2`, because the entire list itself is marked as potentially null as well, signified by the last `?` of the type `ArrayList<Lead?>?`.

```
if (leadList2 != null) {
    leadList1.addAll(leadList2.filterNotNull())
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply pass another List instance into the constructor of your new List

```
val originalList = arrayListOf(1,2,3,4,5)

val orginalListCopy = ArrayList(originalList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:
leadList1.addAll(leadList2.orEmpty().filterNotNull())

And to filter by property you can do like this:

leadList1.addAll(leadList2.orEmpty().filter { item -> item?.type == YourTypeString })